# How can I recreate .npmrc file?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, command-line-interface

So, I was trying to fix an SSL cert error, and I deleted my .npmrc file as a potential solution. I don't think this was the right move because I keep getting an EISDIR error no matter what I do.

I tried deleting/changing/repairing nodejs on my machine but due to admin access (I'm on a company computer), I can't do anything.

I thought the best way might be to just recreate the file I deleted and I am having trouble finding its contents online. Does anyone have a good resource for where to find its contents or would you be willing to share yours?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: in mine (is default), it simply has `registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/` in it, missing file might not be the reason for EISDIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PowerShell:

I made a new file with the contents "registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/", thanks to @Lawrence Cherone in a comment:

```
New-Item -Path . -Name ".npmrc" -ItemType "file" -Value "registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

This didn't solve my EISDIR issue, but I got the file I wanted back!

Comment: I don't understand why you need the file at all, since the default is the official registry anyway. Did you open questions for the SSL cert issue and for the EISDIR problem too? EISDIR means that some path is a directory when it was expected to be a file, that has nothing to do with that.

Comment: True - Turns out I don't need that file. I thought I did but I was wrong. I was just following other people's ideas for while though none have helped. 
I have not opened up new questions for my other errors because I don't think I am able to ask them in a way they have not been asked before so they'd be duplicates.